# Get List of all Html pages names in Mvc 5 Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am making an mvc 5 application, instead of views I have used html pages. Now what I want is to get the list of all the pages name in my application using jQuery / Javascript but didn't find any help. Please suggest some way to do this.
I will next store these names in database.

Comment: a) why on earth didn't you use views? That's really the whole point of the MVC framework. And b) What's the purpose of this? Have you got so many pages you can't count them yourself and add to the database? And c) I don't think you can do this in javascript - it can't read from the server's disk, and it certainly can't insert into the database (unless you plan to use node.js or something)

Comment: @ADyson I integrate theme in my mvc application they used html pages instead of views that's why i used html pages.I know buddy but sometimes you have to do some work which isn't really made for. b) i want to generate the list of all the pages which are included in our application so that whenever i make html page it will show in the list automatically instead to add in the list manually.i don't want to add html page manually one by one, because we are programmers not data entry operator

Comment: @ADyson c) can be the answer because you don't know the answer, i shared this on this platform because i don't know the answer and similarly u too, but maybe someone knows how to do it.

Comment: you can do themes using MVC by using layout views. Just copy/paste the the HTML from the theme into the MVC views. Or you can include static HTML files into your MVC view if you really want. And no I really don't think you can enumerate your files and folders using javascript. It's a security restriction in your browser. Node.js is server-side javascript, so you could do it with that possibly. But not with regular browser-based JS. The answer just posted is your best option I think.

Comment: @Farhan Do you get any best solution?

Answer (score 5):

It is never possible to read the files from IIS by JavaScript or JQuery. Better you can directly add those file names in DB by manually.

Mainly i worried by your question, please try to use Views instead of HTML.

You can do this by .Net

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/"));
FileInfo[] fileInfo = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.html", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Then you can write this in MVC Controller method, then call it by JQuery AJAX.

Comment: @Farhan Do you got any best solution on this?

Comment: Yup get all the pages names in controller then convert it into Json and pass the names to javascript file and use it.

Comment: @Farhan That is what I mentioned in my answer. :)